# Почему 2 одинаковых сайта, очень по разному индексируются?

Tags: seo, google-search

Есть 2 сайта, они одинаковые, контент одинаковый но тот сайт что более старый, import-motor он имеет в поисковой выдаче всего 8к страниц.
А другой сайт, более новый, имеет 323k страниц.

Почему так сильно отличается их индексация?

Вот скриншоты из Google Search Console:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как минимум, технически это разные сайты, которые реализованы при помощи отличного друг от друга стека технологий, а значит может отличаться и микроразметка и еще куча всего.

Comment: эти сайты одинаковые, я их сделал

Comment: Ну да, они одинаковы, только вот визуально они отличаются, хоть и не очень значительно и один из них на Laravel Livewire, а второй нет.

Comment: На одном есть robots, на втором не нашел, у Вас даже ошибки 404 там по-разному обрабатываются. На старом будет действительно 404, на втором бросает на каталог.

Comment: это же мелочи, не думаю что обработка 404 так уж и сильно влияет на индексацию страниц

Comment: Да, но эти мелочи указывают на то что эти два сайта НЕ ИДЕНТИЧНЫ и поисковая система обращает внимание на все мелочи, так как помимо самого контента есть еще десятки или сотни факторов которые учитываются, начиная от вашего доменного имени и его возраста, заканчивая семантической версткой или ошибками возникающими на сайте, активность обновления контента и прочее. Если есть эти мелочи, наверняка есть еще туча других "мелочей" и отличий.

Comment: Да и даже если бы они были целиком идентичны, почему Вы думаете что они должны одинаково индексироваться в поиске? Поисковая система обращает внимание на уникальность контекта и авторитетность доменов в том числе.

Comment: так домены новые, и контент одинаковый

Comment: Не совсем понимаю что конкретно Вас смущает. Если посмотреть на сайты, то здесь прям на главной выводите каталог с пагинацией [https://autobid.auction/](https://autobid.auction/), а здесь 18 карточек и популярные бренды [https://import-motor.com/](https://import-motor.com/). Поисковому боту чтобы индексировать, нужно ходить по ссылкам которые где-то залинкованы у Вас же на сайте. На втором сайте это более затруднительно. Чтобы найти nissan, мне нужно лезть в поиск, а на первом бот может просто по страничкам пагинации походить, грубо говоря. Добавьте sitemap в конце концов.

Comment: сайтмапы есть у обеих сайтов, и они одинаковые

Comment: [Why Pages Aren’t Indexed: Fix Search Console Errors](https://breaktheweb.agency/seo/why-pages-arent-indexed/), [Page Indexing report](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7440203?hl=en)